# Returning data from the server in C# via AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I am using an AJAX call to display information based on success or failure of some logic written in C#. I now need to return additional data back from the server and display it. The data I need is contained in the `employers` and `agencies` variables. How can I return that data in my `return Json` statement along with the `success`?

```
$.ajax({
    url: rootpath + "/clients/hasDuplicateTaxId",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.success) {
            // success
        }
        else {
            // fail
        }
    },
    error: function (response) {
        var error = response;
    }
});
```

```csharp
if (taxIdExists)
{
    var employers = _employerRepository.GetByTaxId(taxId).ToList();
    var agencies = _employerRepository.GetByTaxId(taxId).Select(e => e.GeneralAgency).ToArray();
    return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

return Json(new { success = false, error = "Error" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Add the `employers` and `agencies` variables to the anonymous type you provide to the `Json` response. You can then access the properties/objects/arrays they expose in the `data` variable of your JavaScript. It's impossible to give you anything more concrete than that, as you haven't shown us what those classes actually look like.

Comment: See what you did with the `error` member in the C# code? Do the same thing for the other ones too.

Comment: how would that look? something like this?
return Json(new { success = true, employers = employers, agencies = agencies }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: That's right. I added an answer with an example for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `employers` and `agencies` variables to the anonymous type you provide to the `Json`, like this:

```
if (taxIdExists)
{
    var employers = _employerRepository.GetByTaxId(taxId).ToList();
    var agencies = _employerRepository.GetByTaxId(taxId).Select(e => e.GeneralAgency).ToArray();
    return Json(new { success = true, employers, agencies }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

From there you can access the arrays stored in those properties in the `success` handler of your `$.ajax` call:

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data.success) {
        console.log(data.employers);
        console.log(data.agencies);
    }
    else {
        // fail
    }
},
```

They will be arrays, so you would need to loop through them to extract the required information.

Comment: After I add those variables to my anonymous type, I drop into the error setting of my Ajax request.

Comment: What's the error you're getting? You can set a breakpoint to find it, or check the state of the request in the console.

Comment: I set a breakpoint and it hits inside of the `error: function (response)' How do I tell what the error is?

Comment: Use the network tab of the console, or set the breakpoint in your C# code to step through.

Comment: Ah, a circular reference was detected while serializing the Employer object